# Laravel Validation nullable or numeric

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.4.

I have two fields in a form:
travel_km and travel_rate

1. Both fields must be numeric
2. Both fields are optional but, travel_rate must be entered if travel_km is not empty

My rules:
    'travel_km' => 'numeric|nullable',
    'travel_rate' => 'sometimes|required_with:travel_km'

The problem is if travel_km is empty I still get an error on travel_rate because it is null.

If I put nullable on travel_rate I do not get an error even if travel_km is not empty.

To solve this I did this in my Controller:

```
if(empty($request->travel_km) && empty($request->travel_rate)) {
        $this->validate($request,
        [
            'customer_id' => 'required',
            'service_date' => 'required',
            'labour_hrs'    => 'numeric|nullable',
            'hourly_rate' => 'sometimes|required_with:labour_hrs',
        ],
        [
            'customer_id' => 'Please enter the customer',
            'service_date' => 'Please select the service date',
            'labour_hrs' => 'Please enter a valid number',
            'hourly_rate' => 'Please enter a valid number',
        ]);
       } else {
        $this->validate($request,
        [
            'customer_id' => 'required',
            'service_date' => 'required',
            'labour_hrs'    => 'numeric|nullable',
            'hourly_rate' => 'sometimes|required_with:labour_hrs',
            'travel_km' => 'numeric|nullable',
            'travel_rate' => 'sometimes|required_with:travel_km'
        ],
        [
            'customer_id' => 'Please enter the customer',
            'service_date' => 'Please select the service date',
            'labour_hrs' => 'Please enter a valid number',
            'hourly_rate' => 'Please enter a valid number',
            'travel_rate' => 'Please enter a valid number',
            'travel_km' => 'Please enter a valid number'
        ]);
    }
```

Is there any other way to solve this? I have this issue if a few cases and I don't want to more generic solution.

I looked at Custom Validation but could not understand how do I check if the travel_km is empty or not.

```
Validator::extend('foo', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        return is_numeric($value) && $parameter ????;
    });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 11):

Try using `required_if` as below

```
'travel_km' => 'numeric|nullable', 
'travel_rate' => 'sometimes|required_if:travel_km'
```

This will validate travel_rate only if travel_km is present and non-empty. Here it will,
allow you to put `travel_km` null
when `travel_km` is not empty and `travel_rate` is empty it will show you error but won't show you error when `travel_km` has null value. 
Hope this helps.

UPDATE: `nullable` validation doesn't works for numeric value.

It can be accomplished by applying conditional rule as below,

```
if( !empty(Input::get('travel_km')) ){
  $rules['travel_km'] = 'numeric';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it gives the same result, still get an error even though travel_km is empty: 'travel_rate' => 'sometimes|numeric|required_if:travle_km, true'

Comment: I would like to add that I did google it and it seems the numeric rule cannot be null because null is not a number, and that's where the problem comes in. That's why I need a custom validation

Comment: @SigalZahavi True. I have updated my answer as well

Comment: Great. Keep coding!